# R Dummies for subsetting data

Tags: r

I have data on the GPS bearing(0-360 degrees) from one place to many other places(A-Z)

I want to create 4 columns of dummy variables, specifically: 0-89 degrees, 90-179 degrees, 180-269 degrees, and 270-360 degrees.  So that each observation (A-Z) will have a 0 in three of the columns, and a 1 in the column that corresponds to its bearing.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.matrix` in combination with `cut`. `cut` creates a factor with the grouping and `model.matrix` generates the dummy data frame.

```
x <- c(0, 67, 90, 183, 352)
res <- model.matrix(~ cut(x, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))-1)
```

the output is then

```
  cut(GPS$gps_bearing, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))(-1,89]
1                                                     1
2                                                     1
3                                                     0
4                                                     0
5                                                     0
  cut(GPS$gps_bearing, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))(89,179]
1                                                      0
2                                                      0
3                                                      1
4                                                      0
5                                                      0
  cut(GPS$gps_bearing, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))(179,269]
1                                                       0
2                                                       0
3                                                       0
4                                                       1
5                                                       0
  cut(GPS$gps_bearing, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))(269,360]
1                                                       0
2                                                       0
3                                                       0
4                                                       0
5                                                       1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`cut(GPS$gps_bearing, c(-1, 89, 179, 269, 360))`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Now the columns names aren't pretty and should probably be changed, but the matrix is as you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Binning the temperature using **cut**
**Step2:** Creatinng dummies by **createDummyFeatures** (present in **mlr** library)

```
install.packages("mlr")
library(mlr)

a             <- data.frame(cbind(state=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), 
                                  temperature=c(0,12,89,90,180,350,360)))
a$temperature <- as.numeric(levels(a$temperature))[a$temperature]
a$bucket      <- cut(a$temperature,c(0,89,179,269,360), 
                 labels=c("0-89","90-179","180-269","270-360"),include.lowest=TRUE)
createDummyFeatures(a,cols="bucket")
```

**My Output:**

```
|sno   |state |temperature |bucket.0.89 |bucket.90.179 |bucket.180.269 |bucket.270.360
|1     |a     |0           |1           |0             |0              |0
|2     |b     |12          |1           |0             |0              |0
|3     |c     |89          |1           |0             |0              |0
|4     |d     |90          |0           |1             |0              |0
|5     |e     |180         |0           |0             |1              |0
|6     |f     |350         |0           |0             |0              |1
|7     |g     |360         |0           |0             |0              |1
```

Let me know in case of any queries.